# what changes the URL of a request?

Tags: url, ssl, iis, certificate

I am inconsistently getting errors when trying to download a file that is located on my server from my client app. The error is the request URL not matching the certificate CN. In the error, the request URL is the server IP but the CN on the certificate is the domain name, and there is no SAN entry for the IP in the certificate, so I guess this is the cause of the error. The certificate has 2 SAN entries, say mydomain.com and www.mydomain.com .
My client app uses the domain name for requests, so here is my question:
where does the domain name get changed into the IP?
I checked my IIS server and there are no rewrite rules in my webapp (neither redirections); I do have a binding for my IP address though, can that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea about the specific content of the correct certificate, of the setup of the server, of the behavior of the multiple unspecified systems and applications and of the URL you consider the correct one. But I can imaging the following problems:

- Depending on the application it might or might not use [Server Name Indication (SNI)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) and depending on the setup of the server this might result in serving a different certificate.
- Depending on the application it might look at the CN for verification or it might not. The standard says that CN should only be consulted if there is no SAN (Subject Alternative Names) DNS record but various applications consult the CN even is there a SAN DNS record while others don't consult the CN even if there is no SAN DNS record but only a SAN IP record. And some insist on not looking at the CN even if there are no SAN records at all.
- If the URL is not per domain but an IP address then some applications correctly check against the SAN IP record, some check against CN and some ignore any SAN IP records but wrongly expect the IP address to be contained in a SAN DNS record.
- Apart from that different applications might actually use slightly different URLs, i.e. some `example.com`, some `www.example.com`, some start with HTTP and some with HTTPS. This might result in different certificates or redirects depending on the servers setup.

Thus to reduce problems make sure that you have only a single certificate which gets served no matter if SNI or not is used and no matter which of the possible URLs gets used. Also make sure that the certificate actually contains every domain name you expect as SAN DNS record. And if you expect the site to be accessed by IP address instead domain in the URL make sure that you have both SAN IP and SAN DNS records. Also, any redirects you have should all point to exactly the same domain name or IP address.

Once this is done and the problem persist try with a new post at Stackoverflow where you add enough details about site setup, contents of certificates and the exact problems with exactly which clients so that the problems can be reproduced by others and they can help you with debugging the remaining problems.

Comment: sorry it is hard to understand if you speak about client or server application; I also clarified my question in this regard. Thanks for you answer

Comment: @guillaume: I'm talking about client site checks here only. But it is impossible to say from your information where the hostname in the URL gets changed to an IP address as you claim. This might be some rewrite you did not detect or it might be a bug in the client. If the problem could be reproduced with a browser you might use the browsers developer tools to look exactly which requests are made and responses received and thus find out where the use of IP instead of hostname comes from.